# MongoSkin don't work with req.params.id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

I have this strange issue using mongskin 
for example

```
db.collection('collection_name')
.find({integer_id:req.params.id})
.ToArray(function(err,result){
console.log(result);
});
```

however the result will be empty array [ ]
I tried to console.log(req.params.id) and the result is the integer number for example 1

if I use the number directly like

```
db.collection('collection_name')
.find({integer_id:1})
.ToArray(function(err,result){
console.log(result);
});
```

in this case the result will be fetched successfully

---

I don't know what is the issue exactly, is this is a character encoding issue? or something like that?

and please if there's any way to make sure that the req.params.id will work correctly with the database if there's any encoding issue

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integer_id` suggests that the id should be a `Number`, and not a `String`, which is what `req.params.id` will be.

So try this:

```
.find({ integer_id : Number(req.params.id) })
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfect for my Application